# Effect of exogenous parameter on three player SPNE profits

Tags: game-theory, profit-maximization

Consider three agents $A_i$.

- $A_1$ moves first and selects $0\leq q_1\in \mathbb{R}$. $A_2$ moves second and selects $0\leq q_2\in \mathbb{R}$. $A_3$ moves third and selects $0\leq p_1\in \mathbb{R}$ and $0\leq p_2\in \mathbb{R}$.  $0\leq x\in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter.
- $A_1$ tries to maximize $u_1(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$, with $\frac{\partial u_1(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)}{\partial q_1}\geq 0$ and $\frac{\partial u_1(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)}{\partial p_1}\geq 0$, and independent of $q_2,p_2,x$. $u_1(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$ is continuous in all its inputs.
- $A_2$ tries to maximize $u_2(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$, with $\frac{\partial u_2(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)}{\partial q_2}\geq 0$ and $\frac{\partial u_2(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)}{\partial p_2}\geq 0$, and independent of $q_1,p_1,x$. $u_2(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$ is continuous in all its inputs.
- $A_3$ tries to maximize $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$, with $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$ increasing for all $p_1<\bar{p}$ and decreasing for all $p_1\geq \bar{p}$; $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$ decreases in $x$ and $q_1$; and $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2\rightarrow \infty, x)=-\infty$; $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2\rightarrow \infty,p_2, x)=-\infty$. $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$ is continuous in all its inputs, but we do not know more about its properties for $p_2,q_2$.
- We assume that in case that an agent is indifferent between two or more strategies that there exists a decision rule that selects exactly one of these strategies. These rules are known by all agents.

The existence of a unique SPNE is quite clear. However, there could be multiple other equilibria that would lead to the same profit profile (specifically equilibria in which each agent gains the same profits.)

**Question:** Does $A_3$'s profit decrease in $x$? If yes, why? If not, is there an easy assumption that we need for $u_3(q_1,p_1, q_2,p_2, x)$ behavior with regard to $q_2,p_2$? (I think I miss the forest for the trees) Does the sum of all agents' profit decrease in $x$?

My immediate intuition is yes, because otherwise $A_3$ would be able to pass on all its "losses" to the other agents.

Comment: Can you please carefully double check your question. There are multiple contradictory sentences and typos. Also what is $t_M$

Comment: I am very sorry for the flod of typos.... I think I got it right this time. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 3):

Let's solve by backward induction.

1. In stage 3, player $A_3$ solves:
   $$
   \max_{p_1, p_2} u_3(p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2, x).
   $$
   Given the assumptions, $A_3$ will set: $p_1 = \overline{p}$ and in general $p_2$ will be a function of the $q_1, q_2$ and $x$, denoted by $p_2(q_1, q_2, x)$. For a solution to exist, you have to assume that $u_3$ is not unbounded in $p_2$.
2. As $u_2$ is independent of $p_1, q_1, x$, In stage 2, Player $A_2$ solves:
   $$
   \max_{q_2} u_2(q_2, p_2(q_1, q_2, x)).
   $$
   $u_2$ is increasing in $q_2$ and $p_2$. If $p_2(q_1, q_2, x)$ is increasing in $q_2$ then $A_2$ will set $q_2$ as big as possible, so there is no optimal solution. Else, there might be some optimal level of $q_2$, say $q_2(q_1, x)$.
3. In stage 1, player $A_1$ solves:
   $$
   \max_{q_1} u_1(q_1, \overline{p}).
   $$
   As $u_1$ is increasing in $q_1$ there will probably be no solution to this. So likely this problem is unbounded. If we assume that $q_1 \le \overline{q}_1$ for some fixed value $\overline{q}_1$, then $A_1$ will set $q_1 = \overline{q}_1$.

Going back to the utility of player 3, we therefore see, after substituting:
$$
u_3 = u_3(\overline{p}, p_2(\overline{q}_1, q_2(\overline{q}_1, x),x), \overline{q}_1, q_2(\overline{q_1}, x), x).
$$
It seems like the change in $u_3$ due to a change in $x$ is ambiguous. As it also influences the optimal choice of $q_2$ (of player $A_2$), and $p_2$ of player $A_3$.

Comment: Thank you very much @tmd. I included two new properties for $u_3$ with regard $p_2$ and $q_2$. I do not yet understand why $A_1$ and $A_2$ who are indifferent to $x$ should essentially take all the losses that arise for $A_3$ when $x$ increases. Do you have the intuition why that might happen? Perhaps I can then add a little bit more structure to rule this behavior out.

Comment: Does the sum of all agents' profit decrease in $x$?